# SSRS 2016 / VS 2015 Editing text in tablix's textbox very slow in designer

Tags: ssrs, reporting, visual-studio, report-builder

Same issue as described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f6bf89cd-75de-49f9-8a3a-743419ecd631/ssrs-2016-editing-text-in-a-textbox-very-slow-in-the-designer?forum=sqlreportingservices

But since those forums are dead as a.. well, a dead thing.. I wanted to re-ask here.

As stated, when designing a report in VS 2015 against SSRS 2016, when I have a **tablix** and go to edit the text in a textbox in that tablix (say, a column header one, where I'm typing something in manually instead of pulling the value from the dataset), it goes V..E..R..Y..S..L..O..W..L..Y. Every character/keystroke takes many fractions of a second, if not OVER one second. It literally took almost 5 seconds to finish typing & previewing the text 'Units' in one box.

Any help, suggestions, things I can disable or check? (And if the answer is "upgrade VS to 2017 or 2019", that is acceptable **IFF** you have legit real-world evidence that it helps! I'm not avoiding the upgrade entirely, I'm just not convinced that it's THE solution to this particular problem!)

I will also say, anecdotally, this doesn't *seem* to have always been true; it seems to have started at some point within the past year-ish, but when specifically I couldn't tell you.

Software:

> - VS Pro 2015: 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
> - BI Developer Extensions for VS 2015: 2.1.1 (formerly BIDS Helper)
> - SQL Server Data Tools 14.0.61707.300
> - SQL Server Reporting Services: 14.0.806.134
> - Redgate SQL Prompt: 9.2.4.6028

System:

> - Core i5-5200U @ 2.2GHz, 12 GB RAM, Samsung 850EVO SSD
> - Windows 10 Enterprise v1809 / build 17753.379

Comment: Note that I immediately suspect SQL Prompt and will try disabling it to see if that helps (and maybe the other 3rd party extension). Also, due-diligence I have *not* yet done: checking vanilla Report Builder to see if it has the same problem, and checking old VS2010/SSRS2008R2 stack to see if it's the same there. I will do those at some point and report back with results. In the meantime, I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Removing both VS add-ins/extensions mentioned had no effect. I noticed my CPU usage was generally high; I took some steps to alleviate that, and it seemed to help *very slightly*. Also, when I type in the textbox, VS's CPU usage spikes.